# List of standard window class names

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a published list of window class names used, such as Edit, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, see [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN - it includes a list in the *Remarks* section.

Comment: Don't forget the Common Controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775491%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).