# Win32 API - How to make resizable textbox similar to text in MS-Paint

Tags: c++, winapi, paint

I tried to replicate *the text button in MS-Paint* for my own simple Paint win32 project using Visual Studio. **The user click the button, select a rectangular area as textbox and then type text in**:

[image: Desirable function]

I have done some research but haven't had any clue how to implement this to my project. I attempted to make a textbox at a specific position on the screen first (after clicking button) and allow user to type text in (i will try to figure out how to allow user to select text area later). Here is a snippet of the code:

```
HWND textbox; //global variable

//LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case IDC_TEXTBOX:
                CreateWindowEx(
                    NULL, L"textbox", L"",
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                    100, 100, 100, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)0, NULL, NULL
                );


                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"CreateTextBox",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 10, 10, 150, 40, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, NULL, NULL);
        break;
```

Here is the result:
[image: first attempt]

It is simple but the code i wrote doesn't work. The textbox won't appear after the button is clicked. Therefore, zero progress is made and i have no idea what to do now. So the questions are: why did my solution fail? and **How do i properly implement *the text button in MS-Paint* to my project?**

Comment: You are asking two distinct questions and it's unclear which one you want answered; How to properly implement text editing or why does your proposed solution fail.

Comment: I have edited my question. The answer for both is appreciated

Comment: You need a proper window class, `"textbox"` isn't one.  See [List of standard window class names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796721/5987).

Comment: The Windows API isn't an API you can discover by guessing. You'll need to get some learning material. Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is a fine choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's comments i have found out the solution and they are:

1. **Why my solution in my question failed:** "textbox" is not a proper window class. In this case, i changed them to EDIT (more about [EDIT control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls)) and the window i need appears.
2. **How to implement *the text button in MS-Paint* to my project**: while user is holding left mouse button and dragging mouse to select text area, we draw a rectangle. When left mouse button is up (user is done with selecting text area), we create a window in the area of the rectangle. Here is the code for that:

```
int fromX, fromY;
int toX, toY;
bool isPreview;
bool isDrawingTextbox = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_CREATE, OnCreate);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, OnCommand);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_PAINT, OnPaint);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, OnLButtonDown);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, OnLButtonUp);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, OnMouseMove);

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL OnCreate(HWND hwnd, LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"CreateTextBox",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 10, 10, 150, 40, hwnd,
        (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, NULL, NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

void OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case IDC_TEXTBOX:
        isDrawingTextbox = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void OnDestroy(HWND hwnd)
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}

void OnPaint(HWND hwnd)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    if (isDrawingTextbox) {
        HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_DASHDOT, 3, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        Rectangle(hdc, fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
    }
 

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

void OnLButtonDown(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
{
    isPreview = true;
    fromX = x;
    fromY = y;

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    MoveToEx(hdc, x, y, NULL);
}

void OnLButtonUp(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
{
    isPreview = false;
    
    if (isDrawingTextbox) {
        if (toY < fromY) {
            int temp = fromY;
            fromY = toY;
            toY = temp;
        }

        if (toX < fromX) {
            int temp = fromX;
            fromX = toX;
            toX = temp;
        }

        int width = abs(fromX - toX);
        int height = abs(fromY - toY);
        CreateWindowEx(
            NULL, L"EDIT", L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE,
            fromX, fromY, width, height, hwnd, (HMENU)0, NULL, NULL
        );
    }
}

void OnMouseMove(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
{
    if (isPreview) {
        toX = x;
        toY = y;

        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
}
```

This is my own solution to the problem. Feel free to answer with your better solution.